Can't get Python to publish .csv to ArcGIS Portal
I built and published an address locator so it could be available as a geocoding service on our internal ArcGIS enterprise Portal. I now want to build a tool in Python that can be published as a geoprocessing service that allows the end user to upload a CSV file that gets published to Portal so it can be geocoded.
The first part of the script imports the necessary modules and then connects to Portal using an account with "creator" privileges. Once I get to the publishing section I only get a message that the job failed. Anything I can do to get past this?
Here is my code:
# Import necessary modules.
import arcpy
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode

# connect to the GIS enterprise portal.
gis = GIS("https://myportal.mybiz.com/arcgis", "username", "password")
 
# Specify the path to the table
table_path = r"C:\Data\GeoTest6.csv"

# Define the properties of the item
item_properties = {
    "title": "GeoCodeTest6",
    "type": "CSV",
    "tags": ["geocode", "internal", "tbd"],
}

table_item = gis.content.add(item_properties, data=table_path)

# Add the table to the portal
try:
    # Start the publish job
    publish_job = table_item.publish()

    # Wait for the job to complete
    publish_job.status

    # Check the job messages
    for msg in publish_job.messages:
        print(msg)

    # Get the published table
    published_table = publish_job.result()
except Exception as e:
    print("Publishing failed with message: {}".format(str(e)))

Here is the error message:
Publishing failed with message: Job failed.

